# Only one screen in Lua MAME

Tags: lua, emulation

In Lua script for MAME, when playing a game in two screens mode, when running this script :

```
for i,v in pairs(manager:machine().screens) do print(i) end
```

It only returns me

```
:screen
```

My goal is to to draw differents objects on each screen.